# Find span with 2 attributes Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Just trying to code a web scraper with selenium which searchs for a span in a div which has an other span with a title in it.

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-6 attributes-column"><div class="p-3 bg-color-third d-flex flex-column border-radius-8px h-100 position-relative attributes-main"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAD4SURBVHgB3ZXNEYIwEIVfGA/iiRLszBawArACpQOtDDrAEwkX1iyQ8WY2BDj4zfAzzNtskn1sgI1R7qXXfUFEuf2SeaMIb3t/Hk/HqyiBMeZug3IEQqBbmqalV2g60xptSGt9hgDWsb43fSvRg8V8IQBpzAHLacTKJSuQkmBjRFsUY2HvCtjC1o6laHCGdQq5dVr5HeRHDWIt7K/BPHP7QzUQ4HR2SzNZgkimBFNhIN2G4ASkqOKngqrnetRYiTEBN6yBhsqtZFdi+9RORf7vBIEWdjql1BjnbXZsYWvfYrYwpNBArzGRRNx13SNBcpF2U56U6Kxegw+CobhgOuqV7gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="copy"><span class="fs-11px text-uppercase letter-spacing-3 text-truncate tw-text-secondary" title="Total Volume (ALL Time, ALL Marketplaces)">Total Volume (ALL Time, ALL Marketplaces)</span><span class="text-white fs-14px text-truncate attribute-value" title="5325.23 ◎">5325.23 ◎</span></div></div>
```

The problem is that there are multiple divs with this class. So I have to find only this div which has the span with the title=Total Volume (ALL Time, ALL Marketplaces) in it and then print the span with the class=text-white fs-14px text-truncate attribute-value

Can anyone help me with this problem?
So I only can scrap the right span in the div?

Thank you very much <3

Comment: I think this would be helpful : WebElement el=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div//span[contains(text(),'Total Volume')]//following-sibling::span"));
  System.out.println(el.getText());

Comment: This works fine! But I have to code it for Python, so this is now my final solution: `for elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div//span[contains(text(),'Total Volume')]//following-sibling::span"):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would be helpful :
WebElement el=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div//span[contains(text(),'Total Volume')]//following-sibling::span"));
System.out.println(el.getText());

Answer (score 0):

You can locate the `span` with `class=text-white fs-14px text-truncate attribute-value` by several ways. I would prefer this XPath:

```py
//div[contains(@class,'attributes-column') and .//span[@title='Total Volume (ALL Time, ALL Marketplaces)']]//span[contains(@class,'attribute-value')]
```